# How to set value in Cookie then how to get in server side

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-cookie

How to set value on the cookie in client side then after i need to get value in server side .

Could please give me one example i would really appreciate you

Answer (score 1):

Create cookie:

```
document.cookie="cookiename=John Doe";
```

Read cookie:

```
Request.Cookies(cookieName)
```

More reading about cookies:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/ASP/asp_cookies.asp